# Which part of my function is causing TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float?

Tags: python, loops, typeerror

I am creating a median_filter function for an assignment. Here is my code:

```
def median_filter(y, W):
    """ (list, int) -> list
    
    Returns a list whose ith item is
    the median value of y[start:stop+1] where
    start is the larger of 0 and i - W and
    stop is the smaller of i + W and n-1.
    
    >>> median_filter([-1.0, 6.0, 7.0, -2.0, 0.0, 8.0, 13.0], 1)
    [2.5, 6.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 10.5]
    """

        
    for i, element in enumerate(y):
        
        ynew = []
        
        if i-W >= 0 and i+W < len(y):  
            ynew.append([my_median([y[i-W],y[int(i)], y[i+W]]) for i in y])
            
        
        if i-W < 0 and i+W < len(y): 
            ynew.append([my_median([y[0], y[1]]) for i in y])
            
            
        if i-W >= 0 and i+W >= len(y):
            ynew.append([my_median([y[len(y)-2], y[len(y)-1]]) for i in y])
            
        i+=1
        
    return ynew
```

It gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\****\", line 339, in <listcomp>
        ynew.append([my_median([y[i-W],y[int(i)], y[i+W]]) for i in y])
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

Why am I getting this error? How can i resolve it?

edited to add instructions to function:
[image]

Comment: This would be trivial to solve if you used a debugger, like the free one in the free IDE PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html All you have to do is run the program in debug mode, and then you can see the exact values of each variable at the moment that error happened. Learning to debug your own code is something you should learn ASAP. It should be a day 1 thing, but the second best time to learn it is now.

Comment: `i-W` and `i+W` are floats.  You get in trouble by reusing the `i` variable.  Inside your list comprehension, `i` is an element of `y`.  It's not your enumeration counter.

Comment: Your second and third clauses are going to append the exact same number `len(y)` times.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: You also are going to need to instantiate `ynew` *outside* your for loop. Elsewise it will be re-created on each iteration and you will lose the previous values.

Comment: @TimRoberts why would those be floats? `enumerate()` returns indices as integers. `element` would be the float, whereas `i` would be an integer index. `W` might be a float, but that would mean that the function is being called incorrectly, which we have no way of knowing since we can't see how it's being called.

Comment: @TimRoberts I edited my post to add my instructions for the function, I thought I did the clauses all right but I am not sure now

Comment: @NathanielFord thank you I took your suggestion, I didn't think of that

Comment: @RandomDavis my function is being called with the example in my docstring if thats what you are asking (im not sure but)

Comment: @RandomDavis Your comment reads rather harshly. Learning is a road that has many entrance points, and while it's valid to say that this is a good opportunity to learn a debugger, because it's a helpful tool here, we should avoid even the whiff of belittling someone who hasn't learned to use one yet.

Comment: @RandomDavis  Because he REUSED `i` in the list comprehension.  Within the list comprension, `i` is NOT the `enumerate` result.  It's an element of `y`.

Comment: @TimRoberts oh, of course, yeah I missed that.

Comment: @NathanielFord good point, I guess it's just disappointing to see so many questions that could be solved with trivial debugging knowledge. I'm not sure why so many people seem to not utilize it since it's so critical.

Comment: @RandomDavis I hear what you are saying, but I've learned in my 45 years of programming that debugging is a genetic trait.  Some people have it, and some people just don't.

Comment: @TimRoberts On a short enough timeline, no one knows how to debug. We should be kind to people, and teach, not sort them into categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code they were trying to get you to write.

```
def median_filter(y, W):
    """ (list, int) -> list
    
    Returns a list whose ith item is
    the median value of y[start:stop+1] where
    start is the larger of 0 and i - W and
    stop is the smaller of i + W and n-1.
    
    >>> median_filter([-1.0, 6.0, 7.0, -2.0, 0.0, 8.0, 13.0], 1)
    [2.5, 6.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 10.5]
    """

    ynew = []

    for i in range(len(y)):
                
        if i-W >= 0 and i+W < len(y):  
            val = my_median( y[i-W:i+W+1] )
                    
        elif i-W < 0 and i+W < len(y): 
            val = my_median( y[0:y[i+W+1] )
                        
        elif i-W >= 0 and i+W >= len(y):
            val = my_median( y[i-W:] )

        ynew.append( val )
            
    return ynew
```

Even easier is:

```
    ynew = []
    for i in range(len(y)):
        ynew.append( my_median( y[max(0,i-W):min(i+W+1,len(y))] ) )
    return ynew
```

Comment: this returns IndexError: list index out of range, does that mean I did everything wrong

Comment: Yes, you have misinterpreted the instructions.  You are confusing the index of an item with the value of the item.  I will redo this so it actually solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you, i remember you actually helped me yesterday too, you are very helpful

Comment: Thank you again it worked :)

Comment: I suggest you take a few minutes to compare what I've done here with the text in your problem statement, just to see how things line up.